# PHP custom function with as syntax, function ($x as $y)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I'd like to implement a for loop using the $array as $element syntax in an anonymous function

Is this possible? I can't use forEach as the $array is actually an object, and forEach doesn't copy the object as it would with an array

I'm using laravel so I'm trying to write a blade directive like forEach but in a way that it makes a copy of the object.

something like:

```
Blade::directive('safeForEach', function ($array as $el){
return '<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++){ ?>';
});
```

where after @safeForEach is called, I can use each $el.

```
Blade::directive('endSafeForEach', function (){
return '<?php { ?>';
});
```

Any ideas please? I've tried to find the source for the blade directive but can't find it.
Thanks

Comment: if you have access to the class code (i.e custom class), I would suggest to implement [iterator interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) or one of the [SPL.iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) on your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `directive` command's callback takes a single parameter which is the string that is passed in the directive **which you need to parse**. You can check the [source code of Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/Concerns/CompilesLoops.php#L91) and adapt it to your own needs:

```
Blade::directive('safeForEach', function ($expression) {
        preg_match('/\( *(.*) +as *(.*)\)$/is', $expression, $matches); 
        $iteratee = trim($matches[1]);
        $iteration = trim($matches[2]);
        $initLoop = "\$__currentLoopData = {$iteratee}; \$__env->addLoop(\$__currentLoopData);";
        $iterateLoop = '$__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop();'.$iteration.'=clone '.$iteratee.'[$i]';

        return '<?php '. $initLoop.' for ($i = 0; $i < count('.$iteratee.'); $i++) { '.$iterateLoop.' ?>';
});
Blade::directive('endSafeForEach', function () {
        return '<?php } ?>';
});
```

If for example you pass `@safeForEach($a as $b)` this *should* compile to:

```
$__currentLoopData = $a;
$__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData);
for ($i = 0;$i < count($a);$i++) { 
    $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); 
    $loop = $__env->getLastLoop();    
    $b = clone $a[$i];
```

however you need to ensure that

1. `$iteratee` is countable
2. `$i` does not conflict. Laravel uses a variable called `$__env` to store loop information and assumes that it's not used elsewhere but given the name it's less likely to be used.
3. `clone` will only make a shallow copy of an object and might break for non-clonable elements so you might also need to refine that part

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info! I'm now trying to use that expression to parse the string, but also trying to include the loop logic from CompilesLoops. I've included a use CompilesLoops trait which seems to work, but I'm getting an Undefined property: Illuminate\View\Factory::$loop (View: /home/vagrant/machinedown/resources/views/cards/site.blade.php) Error!

Comment: Added an update that is more close to the Laravel source. I don't think it's required to match it to this extend though, so adapt it as you please